# Migration errors starting a Rails project on a new laptop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I'm trying to launch a Rails project on a new laptop and have some errors in few old migrations (attributes are no longer present for some models etc).

I commented those migrations and `rake db:migrate` finished successfully. I've got a database dump and everything seems to be working fine.

Is it ok that some migrations were commented? Can it affect something in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run all the migrations when preparing a new database instance. In fact for larger projects it may not be possible or too complex.

Instead restore your latest database state from a snapshot if you have one or run `rails db:setup` to have a database with the latest schema created from your `db/schema.rb`. Read more in [Active Record Migration docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#setup-the-database).

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to revert `rake db:migrate` somehow?

Comment: As it says in the mentioned docs, you can run `rails db:reset` which will drop and recreate your database with the schema from your `db/schema.rb`. The data will not be there. This way you will not have to rollback any migrations.

Comment: It worked, although I had to use `rake db:reset`, not `rails db:reset`

Comment: Right. The link I've sent was for edge Rails, might be a change in Rails 5. I usually do `rake` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your db/schema file which will let you know the state of your database and see if any of your unwanted fields still exist.  Commenting is fine, though, it may cause confusion later on.